# Python F-String formatting for date like String

Tags: python, format, f-string

I wanted to use F-Strings that Python 3.8 provides to Format a string the way I would like to.

The original String/Strings look like this:

```
25.02.2021
17.02.2021
17.02.2021
17.02.2021
11.03.2021
17.02.2021
17.02.2021
04.03.2021
```

Now I want to change them the "other way around" so I want them to look like this: `2021.03.12` So YYYY.MM.DD

I have tried: `line = f'{line:%Y.%m.%d}'` line is the original Stringname.

But if I use this I get this error:

```
    line = f'{line:%Y.%m.%d}'
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try splitting it with `.` and then join by reversing it.
This is simple solution

```
line = '.'.join(line.split('.')[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is because your data is strings not `datetime`s, and the format specifier `:%Y.%m.%d` only works with `datetime`s. You *can* parse your strings into `datetime`s using `strptime()` but since you just want to reverse the order, you can just do:

```
>>> data = '25.02.2021'
>>> '{}.{}.{}'.format(*reversed(data.split(".")))
'2021.02.25'
```

There are other ways to do this but you seemed to want to do it using string formatting.